# Is there an isPlaying() type function for Animator

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I know you can do animation.isPlaying() but is there something similiar for Animator ? So if I have:

```
Animator animator;

void Start()
{
    animator = GetComponenet<Animator>();
}
```

Then I could go:

```
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))

        Instantiate(shot, shotSpawn.position, shotSpawn.rotation);

            if(!animator.isPlaying("ShootAnimation"))
            {
                animator.SetTrigger("ShootAnimation"); // play shooting animation
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("YourAnimationName"))
{
    // do your magic
}
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation of how exactly this helps, bare code is way from ideal answer.